# C: Fork and signals

Tags: c

What I want to do is create a parent process that lasts for 5 seconds. I also want it to send a `SIGUSR1` signal every second. On this signal I want the child to do something.

The code that I put together so far is:

```
void alarmHandler(int sig) {
    printf("\nalarm called\n");
    exit(0);
}


void childHandler(int sig) {
    printf("child called");
    signal(SIGUSR1, childHandler);
}

int main() {
    pid_t val;

    if((val = fork())) { //parinte
        signal(SIGALRM, alarmHandler);
        printf("parent");
        alarm(5);
        while(1) {
            kill(val, SIGUSR1);
            sleep(1);
        }
    }else { 
        signal(SIGUSR1, childHandler);
        printf("child");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I get is:

```
child
parent
alarm called
```

What I want:

```
child 
parent
child called
child called
child called
child called
child called
alarm called
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent has the `while` loop. The child does the following:

```
signal(SIGUSR1, childHandler);
printf("child");
```

And then exits.

If it does receive `SIGUSR` before the exit, this will also be executed

```
printf("child called");
signal(SIGUSR1, childHandler);
```

Therefore you have a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) as the number of *child called* is printed.

Just put a `while (1) {}` after the `printf("child");`

Comment: now what I get is `parent alarm called`. `child` is no more there, let alone `child called`

Comment: @Andrew - Where have you put the while loop? Should be after this line `printf("child");`

Comment: yes, like this `signal(SIGUSR1, childHandler);
  printf("child");
  while(1) {}`

Comment: 'Twould be better (for CPU consumption) to use `pause()` instead of an infinite while loop.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - You are right. Probably better use of CPU consumption to not compile the program in the first place!

Comment: @Andrew - Yes - Put in a `pause` to keep Jonathan happy

Comment: @EdHeal updated, I put `pause` but still not working as expected. `childHandler` isn't called, not even once.

Comment: 'Twould be better (for CPU consumption) to use `while (1) pause();` instead of an infinite while loop.  Sorry you need a loop, but `pause()` waits for a signal...without consuming CPU.

Comment: @EdHeal the while in parent is called 5 times but `kill(val, SIGUSR1);` is not.

Comment: I think the line `signal(SIGUSR1, childHandler);` should be before the `fork`

Comment: @EdHeal I want the parent to send that signal every second

Comment: @Andrew - The default behavior of USR1 signal is to terminate. Therefore if the parent gets in first before you set up the signal handler, the child terminates. So if you set up the signal handler before the fork the child will inherit it. **NO RACE CONDITION WILL OCCUR**

Comment: @EdHeal ok, I set it up before the fork. Still the `childHandler` prints nothing.

Comment: You need to flush the buffer `fflush`

Answer (score 0):

Base on the original code, add two blocks:

- flush the printf: `setbuf(stdout, NULL);`
- keep the child running: `while (1) pause();`

The code list as follow:

```c
    #include "stdio.h"
    #include "stdlib.h"
    #include <signal.h>

    /* For a real-world program, printing from a signal handler is not very safe.
     * A signal handler should do as little as it can, preferably only setting a flag here or there.
     * And the flag should be declared `volatile`.
     * Real-world example:
     *   I once worked on a system that used an Access database as a back end,
     *   and under certain circumstances a printf() call in a signal handler would write to the .mdb file instead of stdout,
     *   hosing the database beyond repair.
     */
    void alarmHandler(int sig)
    {
        printf("\nparent signal alarm handler: times up\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    void childHandler(int sig)
    {
        printf("\nchild signal handler\n");
        // The old style should install the handler again.
        signal(SIGUSR1, childHandler);
    }

    int main()
    {
        pid_t val;

        signal(SIGALRM, alarmHandler);
        // If not set this, we cann't the child's output.
        // The stdout stream is buffered, so will only display what's in the buffer after it reaches a newline (or when it's told to).
        setbuf(stdout, NULL);
        if ((val = fork())) { //parinte
            printf("\nparent\n");
            // @Note that there is only one alarm clock per process.
            // the alarm() function will return a value if another alarm has been previously set.
            //
            // sets a timer that generates the SIGALARM signal when times up.
            // If we ignore or don’t catch this signal, the process is terminated.
            alarm(5);
            while(1) {
                sleep(1);
                kill(val, SIGUSR1);
            }
            printf("\nparent exit\n");
        } else {
            signal(SIGUSR1, childHandler);
            printf("\nchild\n");
            while (1)
                pause(); // The pause() function suspends the process until a signal is caught.
            printf("\nchild exit\n");
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

And the output:

```
parent
child
child signal handler
child signal handler
child signal handler
child signal handler
parent signal alarm handler: times up
```